# Book sources on termination conditions in genetic algorithms

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm currently writing a paper on genetic algorithms. I'd like to have a small subsection on the termination condition which determines when the algorithm has to stop.

I found this nice site:

http://www.nd.com/genetic/termination.html

which lists some nice methods via which the termination condition in genetic algorithms is determined. However, the professor who's in charge of my paper is very reluctant to accept random internet sites as sources.

Can you give some recommendations on books (would be very good if I can get my hands on them in e-book form) which contain more information about these termination conditions and maybe expand on the various method's advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: I don't think termination criteria are important enough to justify extensive coverage in any book. Most GAs just run for a fixed number of iterations (generations), or a fixed amount of time. If you have a fixed maximum on the fitness function, you can stop it once it's close enough by some measure. The definition of "close enough" depends on the application.

Comment: Open-ended questions like this, soliciting recommendations or opinions, used to be accepted on Stack Overflow. However, producing good answers to questions like that turned out to scale very poorly as the site grew larger and they're now considered off-topic. :(

Comment: How did your paper go? Link? I'm looking for frequency-analysis/noise-floor methods to determine stopping conditions with multimodal solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, although this is a very interesting field of research, it has only received little attention until now.

Although the original question was originally requesting a book, you might be interested in this published article that discuss some termination criteria: On Stopping Criteria for Genetic Algorithms (Martín Safe, Jessica Carballido, Ignacio Ponzoni and Nélida Brignole) at this url: http://www.springerlink.com/content/cgt7635e3lhu3pdn/

You might also be interested in reading a few pages the PhD thesis "Analysis and Improvement of Genetic Algorithms using Concepts from Information Theory" from John Milton, section 3.6 (pages 127 and following), which discuss some termination conditions. Available at: http://epress.lib.uts.edu.au/scholarly-works/bitstream/handle/2100/1004/02Whole.pdf?sequence=2

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably any good general introductory text on genetic algorithms, which are likely to have a brief mention of possible termination criterion. The only such book I had to hand was [A Field Guide to Genetic Programming](http://www.gp-field-guide.org.uk/) (GP being very closely related to GA). In there, there is a short paragraph (section 3.5), which mention maximum number of generations, or "a problem-specific success predicate". In practice these two are the most used, with the latter just meaning stop whenever a complete solution is found.

Comment: Although GP is related to GA, choosing an adequate termination criterion is different for both.

Comment: In most cases termination criteria are not representation dependent, and can be applied to either GA or GP (and most other evolutionary algorithms). The same is true for the selection method. There is little point in putting an artificial barrier between the two research fields simply because the individuals represent different things. They share the same underlying algorithm, so the literature from one is often relevant to the other.